# Proportional editing: Unintended vertex is influenced though it is out of the circle

Tags: proportional-editing

I've recently started practicing blender with tutorials by Belender Guru, and been stuck with Part4 of level1 due to this problem.

When I try to use proportional editing, unintended vertices also move although it's out of the circle of influence (You can see what is happening in the image: the vertex at the right of the circle). I tried what I could think of (changing the size of the circle, turning off and on the snap (When it was off, the same problem occurred.), moving other vertices, etc.. (When I tried putting the unintended vertex beck to the position one by one, another vertex moved!! Although I turned off both snap and proportional editing.))

I am using Blender version 2.83.7. I would like someone to help me. I would appreciate it! Thank you for reading.

[image: The vertex on the right moves together though it's out of the circle.]

Comment: Hi, I can see that you have symmetry on X-axis turned on. Maybe it is broken because you moved a vertices while off the symmetry and now it is not symmetrical anymorey but blender tries to find nearest symmetrical vertex.

Comment: It seems that I need to try from the first. I will learn about symmetry function and try to appropriately turn it off and on. Thank you for your kindness!! You helped me a lot!